# Ciclo For con If de Matlab a Python

Tags: python, matlab

Estoy haciendo este ciclo for con if de matlab a python

```
N=length(t)
for k=1:N,
 if m(k)>=0,
    m1(k)=1; 
    y(k)=cos(omega_c*k*Ts +2*pi*nu*k*Ts/10);
 else
    m1(k)=-1;
 y(k)=cos(omega_c*k*Ts -2*pi*nu*k*Ts/10);
   end
end
```

Y este es lo que tengo en python

```
señal = np.arange(1,len(t))
for k in range (señal):
    if m(k)>=0:
        m1(k)=1
        y(k) = np.cos(omega_c * k * dt + 2 * np.pi * b * k * dt/10)
       
    else:
        m1(k)=-1
        y(k) = np.cos(omega_c * k * dt - 2 * np.pi * b * k * dt/10)
```

pero no se si esta bien estructurado en m1(k) ya que se me complica pasar de matlab a python.

Comment: podrías explicar tu código?, así los que sepan de python y no de matlab podrán ayudar.

Comment: No soy experto en Python, ni tan siquiera principiante, pero has probado a cambiar la instrucción de tu bucle for? yo intentaría poner `for k in range (1, señal, 1)` para que te incremente desde 1 hasta `señal` en pasos de '1', al igual que lo estás haciendo en Matlab. Por otro lado, te recomiendo no utilizar caracteres propios de nuestra lengua como la 'Ñ'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En python se escriben los indices entre corchetes: `m[k]`, `y[k]`, etc. Además, los índices comienzan en 0. Pues debería ser

```py
senal = np.arange(0,len(t)) # en vez de np.arange(1,len(t))
for k in senal:
    ...
```

También se puede hacer un ciclo `for` de manera parecida a tu código Matlab:

```
N = len(t) # en Matlab: N=length(t)
for k in range(N): # en Matlab: for k=0:N-1,
   ...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!